# ARKit: project a feature point found in the ARPointCloud to image space and check to see if it's contained in a CGRect on screen?

Tags: scenekit, arkit

So, I am using ARKit to display feature points in the session. I am able to get the current frame, then its rawFeaturePoints and place geometries in the world space so the user can see them on screen. That is working great.

In the app I then have a quadrant on screen. My objective is to show in screen coordinates feature points that projected would fall inside the 2D quadrant on screen. To do that, I tried this:

1. get feature points as an array of vector_float3
2. for each of those points I then get a SCNVector3 setting the Z component to 0 (near plane)
3. I then call on the ARSCNView:

   public func projectPoint(_ point: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3

This approach does give me 2D points back, but, depending on where the camera is they seem to be way off.

So then, since in ARKit the camera keeps moving around, do I need to take that into account to achieve what I explained?

EDIT:
About flipping the Y of the CGPoint retrieved from the projectPoint call on the camera:

```
/**
 Project a 3D point in world coordinate system into 2D viewport space.

 @param point 3D point in world coordinate system.
 @param orientation Viewport orientation.
 @param viewportSize Viewport (or image) size.
 @return 2D point in viewport coordinate system with origin at top-left.
 */
open func projectPoint(_ point: vector_float3, orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, viewportSize: CGSize) -> CGPoint
```

Remy San mentioned flipping the Y. I tried that and it does seem to work. One difference between what he's doing and what I am doing is that I am not using an SKScene, but I am using SCNScene. Looking at the docs it says:

> ...The projection of the specified point into a 2D pixel coordinate space
>   whose origin is in the upper left corner...

So, what throws me off is that if I don't flip the Y it seems like it's not really working properly. (I'll try to post images to show what I mean). But then if flipping the Y though makes things look better, it goes against the docs. No?

Comment: Hi ! I'm kinda working on the same thing. What I'll be trying is to use the ARCamera.intrinsics matrix that seems to handle all the projection work properly (kind of as the MVP matrices on lower level engines). Have you looked into that ?

Comment: Ok, my last suggestion was completely wrong. The projectPoint method seems to provide some interesting results indeed, but I don't need to set the Z component to 0. I guess this would change the points coordinates based on the anchor and not the device ? I'll keep you posted :)

Comment: Back with some news ! I've tried it and the points are perfectly fine, but I had to do one small tweak to make it work : The Y axis is inverted, on my side at least, between the projected points given by ARKit and the SKScene that I lay over it. When adding a node on my SKScene, I just go with `node.position = CGPoint(x: point.x, y: view.bounds.height - point.y)` and it's working :

Comment: @RemySan do you have a code snippet of what you're doing that works for you?

Comment: I don't understand why you have to flip the Y. I stopped setting the Z = 0 and it seems much better.

Comment: I think the 3D World in which the feature points lives is not relative to your device; It's relative to an anchor placed in there by ARKit, usually at the initial position of device. This anchor is axed with Y pointing upwards to the sky (default config is "following the gravity"). So, removing the Z component will flatten the feature points in a plan that's not the device's. You need to project the feature points, untouched, using the projectPoint method of ARCamera, which will do the necessary math to get your points projected in the screen's plan.

Comment: And, for the Y inversion after the projection, I guess that it's because I use both ARKit and SpriteKit to display my points, and that the origin is placed differently on the screen.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind "setting the Z component to 0"?

Answer (score 0):

I get you are using the intrinsics matrix for you projection. ARkit technology may also give you some extra information. These are the `cameraPoseARFrame`, the `projectionMatrix` and the `transformToWorldMap` matrices. Are you taking them into consideration when transforming from world coordinates to pixel coordinates?

If anyone has a methodology for applying these matrices to the point cloud coordinates to convert them into screen coordinates, could you contribute to my answer please? I think they may provide more precision and accuracy to the final result.

Thank you!

Comment: It seems like you’re asking for clarification. If your intention is to answer the question, can you [edit] your answer to explain why you’re asking this, and what the implications would be in terms of solving their problem? Thank you.